# Reboot after uninstall using WiX

Tags: wix, uninstallation, wix3.5, reboot

Is it possible to reboot after you uninstall? I am using WiX to create my installer.

I understand we can reboot after installing using

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But I want to reboot after uninstalling. Please advice.Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to use Conditional Table. Something like '<ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE</ScheduleReboot>'

Comment: Forgive me for this dumb question, the value inside the <ScheduleReboot> determines when the action should be executed? Rather, what does REMOVE mean here? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Inside <ScheduleReboot> node it is a condition when this action will be executed. When the installer removes the product from the system, it sets REMOVE=ALL.Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371626(v=vs.85).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371194(v=vs.85).aspx. REMOVE it's a windows installer standart property.

Comment: Got it. Thanks buble for the explanation. Not sure how to mark the answer as it is in comments.

Comment: I'm glad. You just can vote up the comment

Comment: @buble, it will be great if you can copy the same comment and make an answer out of that. So that it can be marked as answer by user591410 since that may help others who are looking out for this solution better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Conditional Table:

```
<ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE='ALL'</ScheduleReboot>
```

Inside  node it is a condition even this action will be executed or not.
REMOVE it's a windows installer standart property. When the installer removes the product from the system, it sets REMOVE=ALL.
Look at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/…, msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/….